# Remove some rows with " in front

Tags: tableau-api

I have a CSV file that is causing me serious headaches going into Tableau. Some of the rows in the CSV are wrapped in a " " and some not. I would like them all to be imported without this (i.e. ignore it on rows that have it).

Some data:

```
"1;2;Red;3"
1;2;Green;3
1;2;Blue;3
"1;2;Hello;3"
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a bash prompt hanging around...

You can use `cat` to output the file contents so you can make sure you're working with the right data:

```
cat filename.csv
```

Then, pipe it through sed so you can visually check that the quotes were delted:

```
cat filename.csv | sed 's/"// g'
```

If the output looks good, use the -i flag to edit the file in place:

```
sed -i 's/"// g' filename.csv
```

All quotes should now be missing from filename.csv

If your data has quotes in it, and you want to only strip the quotes that appear at the beginning and end of each line, you can use this instead:

```
sed -i 's/^"\(.*\)"$/\1/' filename.csv
```

Comment: I think @NickP just wants to get rid of the quotation marks and not the whole row " (i.e. **ignore it on rows** that have it)."

Comment: @Alexander  You're totally right.  The way the line break fell on my screen, I read it as "Ignore rows that have it".  I feel silly.   Edited.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant way to do it in Tableau but if you cannot remove it in the source file, you could create a calculated field for the first and last column that strips the quotation marks.

1. right click on the field for the first column choose Create/Calculated Field
2. Use this formula: `INT(REPLACE([FirstColumn],'"',''))`
3. Name the column accordingly
4. Do the same for the last column

Assuming the data you provided fits the data you work on. The assumption is that these fields are integer field (thus the INT() usage). In case they are string fields you would want to make sure that you don't remove quotation marks that belong to the field value.